# Stuck in a while Loop while parsing JSON into an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, json, while-loop

I am pulling data from MySQL into a web page and I can not see while I am stuck in my while loop.

For background I am pulling data from my database and trying to put it into objects that look something like this:

```
var SawtoothPassTrailhead = {
  name: "Sawtooth Pass Trailhead",
  lat:  36.453165,
  long:  -118.596751,
  type: "backpacking", 

  //Title then link
  seekAdventure: [],
  blogs: ['Mineral King Loop â€“ Sequoia National Park (45 Mile Loop) - Backpackers Review' , 'https://backpackers-review.com/trip-reports/sequoia-mineral-king/'],
  youtTube: []
};
```

The JSON data that is coming back from my DB call for my test looks like this:

```
[{"TrailHeadID":"1","TrailHeadName":"Tanner Trail - Grand Canyon","TrailHeadLat":"36.03260","TrailHeadLong":"-111.85250","GuideTitle":"1 Week Traversing the Grand Canyon","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/94-1-week-traversing-the-grand-canyon","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"2","TrailHeadName":"Badger Pass - Yosemite","TrailHeadLat":"37.66480","TrailHeadLong":"-119.66340","GuideTitle":"22 Hours of Driving, 1.5 Days of Snowshoeing, Yosemite National Park","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/79-22-hours-of-driving-1-5-days-of-snowshoeing-yosemite-nationa","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"2","TrailHeadName":"Badger Pass - Yosemite","TrailHeadLat":"37.66480","TrailHeadLong":"-119.66340","GuideTitle":"Snowshoeing to Dewey Point in Yosemite (Socal Hike)r","GuideLink":"https:\/\/socalhiker.net\/snowshoeing-to-dewey-point-in-yosemite\/","GuideMediaType":"blog"},{"TrailHeadID":"3","TrailHeadName":"Descanso Beach - Catalina","TrailHeadLat":"33.35040","TrailHeadLong":"-118.32820","GuideTitle":"Kayak Camping Catalina Island","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/76-kayak-camping-catalina-island","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"4","TrailHeadName":"Trans Catalina Trail","TrailHeadLat":"33.34030","TrailHeadLong":"-118.32620","GuideTitle":"Mini Trans Catalina Trail","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/73-mini-trans-catalina-trip","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"4","TrailHeadName":"Trans Catalina Trail","TrailHeadLat":"33.34030","TrailHeadLong":"-118.32620","GuideTitle":"Backpacking the Trans-Catalina Trail (Bearfoot Theory)","GuideLink":"https:\/\/bearfoottheory.com\/backpacking-the-trans-catalina-trail\/","GuideMediaType":"blog"},{"TrailHeadID":"5","TrailHeadName":"High Sierra Trail","TrailHeadLat":"36.55470","TrailHeadLong":"-118.74890","GuideTitle":"High Sierra Trail Complete Guide","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/22-california-high-sierra-trail-to-mt-whitney'","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"5","TrailHeadName":"High Sierra Trail","TrailHeadLat":"36.55470","TrailHeadLong":"-118.74890","GuideTitle":"High Sierra Trail (SoCal Hiker)","GuideLink":"https:\/\/socalhiker.net\/overview-of-the-high-sierra-trail\/","GuideMediaType":"blog"},{"TrailHeadID":"6","TrailHeadName":"Deer Springs Trail - San Jacinto","TrailHeadLat":"33.75300","TrailHeadLong":"-116.72270","GuideTitle":"Deer Springs Trail","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/26-california-deer-springs-trail-san-jacinto-mountain","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"7","TrailHeadName":"Reflection Canyon","TrailHeadLat":"37.25220","TrailHeadLong":"-110.97350","GuideTitle":"Reflection Canyon","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/24-utah-photographing-reflection-canyon","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"7","TrailHeadName":"Reflection Canyon","TrailHeadLat":"37.25220","TrailHeadLong":"-110.97350","GuideTitle":"Reflection Canyon Backpacking Guide (Clever Hiker)","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.cleverhiker.com\/blog\/reflection-canyon-backpacking-guide","GuideMediaType":"blog"},{"TrailHeadID":"8","TrailHeadName":"Big Pine Lakes - North Fork Trail","TrailHeadLat":"37.12820","TrailHeadLong":"-118.42770","GuideTitle":"North Fork to 2nd Lake Sierra Nevada in a Snow Storm","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/18-california-north-fork-to-2nd-lake-sierra-nevada-in-a-snow-storm","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"8","TrailHeadName":"Big Pine Lakes - North Fork Trail","TrailHeadLat":"37.12820","TrailHeadLong":"-118.42770","GuideTitle":"Hiking To Big Pine Lakes via The North Fork Trail (Trail to Peak)","GuideLink":"https:\/\/trailtopeak.com\/2017\/07\/09\/hiking-to-big-pine-lakes-via-the-north-fork-trail\/","GuideMediaType":"blog"},{"TrailHeadID":"9","TrailHeadName":"Fish Creek Wash Anza Borrego","TrailHeadLat":"33.03872","TrailHeadLong":"-116.09941","GuideTitle":"Jeeping in Fish Creek Wash Anza Borrego","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/99-jeeping-in-fish-creek-wash-anza-borrego","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"}]
```

I am creating objects from the data so I can insert each object as a marker on a google map with a pop-up. The tricky part is anything from the above JSON that starts with the same TrailHeadID needs to be in the same Object so it is the same pop-up bubble on Google Maps. Which is where the wile loop comes in with my code below.

I through a console.log() in right before the end of thw while loop and it looks like its getting caught as a 2, so it processes the first one right and then doesn't increment:

```
function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var localTrailHeadID;
    var trailHeadCounter;
    var TrailHeadObject

    //set array conts all to zero
    var seekAdventureCount;
    var blogsCount;
    var youtubeCount;


    //for each row returned by mySQL
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

      localTrailHeadID = arr[i].TrailHeadID;

      //create new trailhead object
      TrailHeadObject = new Object();

      //set array counters to zero
      var seekAdventureCount =0;
      var blogsCount = 0;
      var youtubeCount = 0;

      //set name lat and long
      TrailHeadObject.name = arr[i].TrailHeadName;
      TrailHeadObject.lat = arr[i].TrailHeadLat;
      TrailHeadObject.long = arr[i].TrailHeadLong;

      //set TrailHeadObject Guide arrays to empty
      TrailHeadObject.seekAdventureGuideList = [];
      TrailHeadObject.blogGuideList = [];
      TrailHeadObject.youTubegGuideList = [];



      //Add trail Guides
      while(localTrailHeadID == arr[i].TrailHeadID ){
        //check first guide media type and add to correct Array
        if(arr[i].GuideMediaType == "SeekAdventure"){
          TrailHeadObject.seekAdventureGuideList[seekAdventureCount] = arr[i].GuideTitle;
          seekAdventureCount = seekAdventureCount + 1;
          TrailHeadObject.seekAdventureGuideList[seekAdventureCount] = arr[i].GuideLink;
          seekAdventureCount = seekAdventureCount + 1;
        }
        if(arr[i].GuideMediaType == "blog"){
          TrailHeadObject.blogGuideList[blogsCount] = arr[i].GuideTitle;
          blogsCount = blogsCount + 1;
          TrailHeadObject.blogGuideList[blogsCount] = arr[i].GuideLink;
          blogsCount = blogsCount + 1;
        }
        if(arr[i].GuideMediaType == "YouTube"){
          TrailHeadObject.youTubegGuideList[youtubeCount] = arr[i].GuideTitle;
          youtubeCount = youtubeCount + 1;
          TrailHeadObject.youTubegGuideList[youtubeCount] = arr[i].GuideLink;
          youtubeCount = youtubeCount + 1;
        }
        console.log(arr[i+1].TrailHeadID);
        localTrailHeadID = arr[i+1].TrailHeadID;

      } //end while loop adding guides

      //add object to array of markers
      markers1[i] = TrailHeadObject;

    }//end for Loop

} //end my function
```

I cant see why the while loop isn't breaking. shouldn't this line break it: `localTrailHeadID = arr[i+1].TrailHeadID;`Based on my input data above?

Comment: The input data contains two objects that have `TrailHeadID` set to `2` (the second and third one).

Comment: Yes but after it parses the second one wouldn't it grab the Trailhead ID for the next one which is 3 and break it?

Comment: No, it won't do that because you never increment `i` inside the `while` loop. It will compare the objects at `i` and `i + 1`.

Comment: Dang, your right! Thanks! now off to figure out the next error....

If you answer this I can mark you as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not incrementing `i` inside the `while` loop

This means that the loops condition will always compare the `TrailHeadID` properties of the `i` and `i + 1` objects in the array. If the array has objects that have the same value for this property, the `while` loop's condition will always be `true`.

Here is how I will do it:

```js
const arr = [{"TrailHeadID":"1","TrailHeadName":"Tanner Trail - Grand Canyon","TrailHeadLat":"36.03260","TrailHeadLong":"-111.85250","GuideTitle":"1 Week Traversing the Grand Canyon","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/94-1-week-traversing-the-grand-canyon","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"2","TrailHeadName":"Badger Pass - Yosemite","TrailHeadLat":"37.66480","TrailHeadLong":"-119.66340","GuideTitle":"22 Hours of Driving, 1.5 Days of Snowshoeing, Yosemite National Park","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/79-22-hours-of-driving-1-5-days-of-snowshoeing-yosemite-nationa","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"2","TrailHeadName":"Badger Pass - Yosemite","TrailHeadLat":"37.66480","TrailHeadLong":"-119.66340","GuideTitle":"Snowshoeing to Dewey Point in Yosemite (Socal Hike)r","GuideLink":"https:\/\/socalhiker.net\/snowshoeing-to-dewey-point-in-yosemite\/","GuideMediaType":"blog"},{"TrailHeadID":"3","TrailHeadName":"Descanso Beach - Catalina","TrailHeadLat":"33.35040","TrailHeadLong":"-118.32820","GuideTitle":"Kayak Camping Catalina Island","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/76-kayak-camping-catalina-island","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"4","TrailHeadName":"Trans Catalina Trail","TrailHeadLat":"33.34030","TrailHeadLong":"-118.32620","GuideTitle":"Mini Trans Catalina Trail","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/73-mini-trans-catalina-trip","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"4","TrailHeadName":"Trans Catalina Trail","TrailHeadLat":"33.34030","TrailHeadLong":"-118.32620","GuideTitle":"Backpacking the Trans-Catalina Trail (Bearfoot Theory)","GuideLink":"https:\/\/bearfoottheory.com\/backpacking-the-trans-catalina-trail\/","GuideMediaType":"blog"},{"TrailHeadID":"5","TrailHeadName":"High Sierra Trail","TrailHeadLat":"36.55470","TrailHeadLong":"-118.74890","GuideTitle":"High Sierra Trail Complete Guide","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/22-california-high-sierra-trail-to-mt-whitney'","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"5","TrailHeadName":"High Sierra Trail","TrailHeadLat":"36.55470","TrailHeadLong":"-118.74890","GuideTitle":"High Sierra Trail (SoCal Hiker)","GuideLink":"https:\/\/socalhiker.net\/overview-of-the-high-sierra-trail\/","GuideMediaType":"blog"},{"TrailHeadID":"6","TrailHeadName":"Deer Springs Trail - San Jacinto","TrailHeadLat":"33.75300","TrailHeadLong":"-116.72270","GuideTitle":"Deer Springs Trail","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/26-california-deer-springs-trail-san-jacinto-mountain","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"7","TrailHeadName":"Reflection Canyon","TrailHeadLat":"37.25220","TrailHeadLong":"-110.97350","GuideTitle":"Reflection Canyon","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/24-utah-photographing-reflection-canyon","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"7","TrailHeadName":"Reflection Canyon","TrailHeadLat":"37.25220","TrailHeadLong":"-110.97350","GuideTitle":"Reflection Canyon Backpacking Guide (Clever Hiker)","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.cleverhiker.com\/blog\/reflection-canyon-backpacking-guide","GuideMediaType":"blog"},{"TrailHeadID":"8","TrailHeadName":"Big Pine Lakes - North Fork Trail","TrailHeadLat":"37.12820","TrailHeadLong":"-118.42770","GuideTitle":"North Fork to 2nd Lake Sierra Nevada in a Snow Storm","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/18-california-north-fork-to-2nd-lake-sierra-nevada-in-a-snow-storm","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"},{"TrailHeadID":"8","TrailHeadName":"Big Pine Lakes - North Fork Trail","TrailHeadLat":"37.12820","TrailHeadLong":"-118.42770","GuideTitle":"Hiking To Big Pine Lakes via The North Fork Trail (Trail to Peak)","GuideLink":"https:\/\/trailtopeak.com\/2017\/07\/09\/hiking-to-big-pine-lakes-via-the-north-fork-trail\/","GuideMediaType":"blog"},{"TrailHeadID":"9","TrailHeadName":"Fish Creek Wash Anza Borrego","TrailHeadLat":"33.03872","TrailHeadLong":"-116.09941","GuideTitle":"Jeeping in Fish Creek Wash Anza Borrego","GuideLink":"https:\/\/www.seekadventure.net\/d\/99-jeeping-in-fish-creek-wash-anza-borrego","GuideMediaType":"SeekAdventure"}];
const getPropName = (o) => {
  if(o.GuideMediaType == "SeekAdventure") {
    return "seekAdventureGuideList";
  } else if (o.GuideMediaType == "blog"){
    return "blogGuideList"
  } else if(o.GuideMediaType == "YouTube") {
    return "youTubegGuideList"; 
  }
  return "unknown";
}

const markers = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  const found = a.find(v => v.id == c.TrailHeadID);
  const propName = getPropName(c);
  if (found) {
    found[propName] = [...(found[propName] || []), c.GuideTitle, c.GuideLink];
  } else {
    a.push({
      id: c.TrailHeadID,
      name: c.TrailHeadName,
      lat: c.TrailHeadLat,
      long: c.TrailHeadLong,
      [propName]: [c.GuideTitle, c.GuideLink]
    });
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(markers);
```

Comment: Thanks I am accepting your answer as correct but also have a short follow on question for guidance.

If I add:  i = i + 1 at the end then I get an error for out of range on the arr[i+1].TrailHeadID on th elast round.

Comment: @searayman That will fix the infinite loop problem but you'll have a new problem if `i + 1` is bigger then `array.lenght - 1`.

Comment: @searayman I've made an edit to the answer to add a solution.

Comment: Thanks! I already think I figured it out after re-writing my code multiple times lol. I am stuck again with it now not loading into google maps, which is really odd. I will be posting a new question here shortly.